# Spring ShedLock without Database

Tags: spring, database, shedlock

I want to disable ShedLock with a configuration yml property. So i don't have to create the table shedlock, if it is not necessary. Is there a way to disable Shedlock usage?

I tried to remove @Bean lockProvider but then I got this message:

> No qualifying bean of type 'net.javacrumbs.shedlock.core.LockProvider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using ShedLock in combination with the `shedlock-spring` dependency, there probably is a `@EnableSchedulerLock` somewhere in your application. Move the LockProvider bean setup together with the annotation to a separate `@Configuration` class and add a `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation, for example:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableSchedulerLock
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "shedlock.enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
public class ShedLockConfig {

    @Bean
    public LockProvider lockProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And add the property

```
shedlock:
  enabled: true
```

To your application.yml